# Why an extra { when importing .xls?

Tags: import

I am trying to import data from a file. If I import a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, I get:

```
{{a,b,c},{e,f,g}}.
```

For example, two curly brackets.

If importing from a [.xlsx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) file I get an extra curly bracket like:

```
{{{a,b,c},{e,f,g}}}
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 13):

[CSV](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/CSV.html):

> Import["file.csv"] imports a CSV file, returning ***an array***.

whereas

[XLSX](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/XLS.html):

> Import["file.xlsx"] imports all sheets of an XLSX file, returning the result as ***a list of arrays***.

If the file contains a single sheet, you can eliminate the extra curly braces  using the second argument of `Import` as in @bobthechemist's answer, or simply using `Part`:

```
Import["<file.xlsx>"][[1]]
```

Comment: I need to buy a new keyboard that doesn't have sticky keys; might have beaten you...

Comment: @bob, speaking of sticky keys -- only a few of the keys on my laptop are working due to a coffee spill; and my external keyboard happens to be our cat's favorite spot, and hence full of cat hair:)

Comment: Thanks both. The learning curve is a killer with Marhematica!  But makes sense once explained.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the comments and the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/XLSX.html), importing from Excel files allows for multiple sheets.  Thus, a single-sheet file will have what you refer to as an "extra" pair of curly braces.  To eliminate this behavior, use:

```
Import["<file.xlsx>",{"Data",1}]
```

The above command will import just the first datasheet.