# how can I use the function AdjacencyGraph correctly?

Tags: mathematica-online

I was told as：

> AdjacencyGraph::matsq: Argument
>   {{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,<<461>>},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,<<461>>},<<48>>,<<461>>}}
>   at position 2 is not a non-empty square matrix.

However, the matrix is imported from Microsoft Excel which is exactly a [511 x 511] square matrix.

Comment: You probably have additional `{}` after importing from excell since it returns a list of sheets contents really. So use `First` and put the result to the `AdjacencyGraph`.

Comment: If that's the case, here's a duplicate: [Why an extra { when importing .xls?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76725/5478)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you've imported Microsoft Excel spreadsheet into Mathematica:

```
(*test data*)
data = Import @ "C:\\Users\\-e\\Documents\\data.xlsx";
```

The output of this would be (given there are 3 columns and 3 rows):

```
(*output*)
{{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}}
```

So in order to get your graph you can do something like this:

```
(*operation, where 'data' is your own imported Microsoft Excel data*)
Flatten[data, 1]
```

The output of the above operation would be as follows:

```
(*output*)
{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}
```

Then if you apply `AdjacencyGraph` you get:

```
AdjacencyGraph @ Flatten[data, 1]
```

[image: output example]